# ArgumentException when setting httpWebRequest.Connection to "Closed"

Tags: c#, php, wpf, apache, httpwebrequest

I am trying to connect to a php apache 2.2.1 webservice like this:

```
        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
        {
            var req = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
            var http = req as HttpWebRequest;
            if (http != null)
            {
                http.Connection = "Close";
                http.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
            }
            return req;
        }
```

But I received an `System.ArgumentException` mean as following "Keep-Alive and Close cannot be set"(This message has been translated from Japanese).

I have no idea why this exception is thrown. I have searched in MSDN and there is an explanation like this `Exception Condition: The value of Connection is set to Keep-alive or Close.`. In this case my `httpWebRequest.Connection` is `null`.

Do you have any idea about the reason of this exception?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why would you want to set `Connection` to `"Close"`?

Comment: Actually, I received this project that was done before (There is not any comment for this class what interact with php service). The method above, I think that they try to get a HttpWebRequest to received data. Perhap, they want to set `Connect` to `Close` for sure that this request has not been excuted.

Comment: Strange, because as you saw on MSDN, setting `HttpWebRequest.Connection` to `"Close"` is not allowed, so it seems that code would always throw an exception, no matter what.

Comment: I completely agree with you. I search many time on google, but nobody use this way. I will disscuss with my team leader. May be this project has been not completed. May be I made a mistake. I'm not sure about that, because I am not a Japanese (I communicate with my team by Japanese).

Comment: I discussed with my team leader. He want to set `Connection` to `Close` because following definition of http protocol: `HTTP/1.1 defines the "close" connection option for the sender to signal that the connection will be closed after completion of the response.`. And one more thing, in the example on this link: `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.connection(v=vs.110).aspx`, there is following code snippet: `
      HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest2 = 
        (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://.....com");
      myHttpWebRequest2.Connection="Close"`

Comment: This is a weird example as it throws an `ArgumentException`. You end up in the 1st catch with the following message written to the Console: `The second HttpWebRequest object has raised an Argument Exception as 'Connection' Property is set to 'Close'`.

Comment: I would just call `Close` once you're done.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In this case, My team use a class that is created in the past. We extend it and only override the method create webrequest. So sad, but we cannot change the request method. So we cannot use the Close method after requesting.

Comment: The actual English error message is "Keep-Alive and Close may not be set using this property.
Parameter name: value". Setting the "Connection" header to "Close" was requested by the service provider. HTTP standards state this header should be set to Close to disable persistent connections and that the Keep-Alive header is ignored unless Connection is set to "Keep-Alive". This is probably just another Microsoft bug.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot explain why setting `HttpWebRequest.Connection` to `Close` or `Keep-alive` throw an ArgumentException. But we can set the `Connection` header to `Close` via the setting `HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive` to `false`.

More infos here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.connection?view=netframework-4.7.2